# Find date and time of installed application in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to know using a Windows script when a specific program was installed, including the date as well as the time. I am able to find the date of installation but not the time.

This tells me how to find date: 
http://ccm.net/faq/10354-determine-the-installation-date-of-software-under-windows

Comment: I'm almost sure that you can retrieve only the date of installation , but not the time

Answer (score 2):

The records cited in the link can be read also with `WMIC` command:

```
wmic product where "Caption like '%node%'" get InstallDate /fomat:value
```

where you can change node with unique enough string.Here's how this can be used from batch file and assigend to variable:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "productname=node"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('wmic product where "Caption like '%%!productname!%%'" get InstallDate /format:value') do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=*" %%$ in ("%%#") do set "%%$"
)

echo %installdate%
```

But the time cannot be received this way.Only the date.To get the time you'll have to query the installed files (with `wmic prodict` you can also get the installation directory)

Comment: Thanks npocmaka, But still it does not answered my question, that is Time :(

Comment: @gsgill76 you'll need to give more details...You can get the installation directory of your product with the `wmic` query.And then you can get the last accessed time of some of the installed files there.But your question is rather sketchy

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually check date and time, you can open installation directory, then right click the exe file- properties and see "accessed" under general tab. You can see installation date and time there. May be there are some scripts available to do this but I'm not sure

Comment: Yes, even i think so, but i dont know what is the installation directory for the program, any other way :)

Comment: Why can't you find installation directory?? usually, it'll be c/program files. If it's not there, you can simply right click shortcut of the program then select properties and see installation path there.

Comment: Thanks user3548321, I understand, I will make a try of that as well.

Comment: NOT able to find any solution directly, but only via installation folder only. Still any one having any other thought on this?